# Weka: Limitations on what one can output as source?

Tags: integration, output, data-mining, weka

I was consulting several references to discover how I may output trained Weka models into Java source code so that I may use the classifiers I am training in actual code for research applications I have been developing.

As I was playing with Weka 3.7, I noticed that while it does output Java code to its main text buffer when use simpler classification (supervised in my case this time) methods such as J48 decision tree, it removes the option (rather, it voids it by removing the ability to checkmark it and fades the text) to output Java code for RandomTree and RandomForest (which are the ones that give me the best performance in my situation).
Note:  I am clicking on the "More Options" button and checking "Output source code:".

Does Weka not allow you to output RandomTree or RandomForest as Java code?  If so, why?  Or if it does and just doesn't put it in the output buffer (since RF is multiple decision trees which I imagine it doesn't want to waste buffer space), how does one go digging up where in the file system Weka outputs java code by default?

Are there any tricks to get Weka to give me my trained RandomForest as Java code?  Or is Serialization of the output *.model files my only hope when it comes to RF and RandomTree?

Thanks in advance to those who provide help.

NOTE:  (As an addendum to the answer provided below) If you run across a similar situation (requiring you to use your trained classifier/ML model in your code), I recommend following the links posted in the answer that was provided in response to my question.  If you do not specifically need the Java code for the RandomForest, as an example, de-serializing the model works quite nicely and fits into Java application code, fulfilling its task as a trained model/hardened algorithm meant to predict future unlabelled instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RandomTree and RandomForest can't be output as Java code.**  I'm not sure for the reasoning why, but they don't implement the "Sourceable" interface.

This explains a little about outputting a classifier as Java code:  [Link 1](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Generating+source+code+from+WEKA+classes)

This shows which classifiers can be output as Java code: [Link 2](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/Sourcable.html)

Unfortunately I think the easiest route will be Serialization, although, you could maybe try implementing "Sourceable" for other classifiers on your own.

Another, but perhaps inconvenient solution, would be to use Weka to build the classifier every time you use it.  You wouldn't need to load the ".model" file, but you would need to load your training data and relearn the model.  Here is a starters guide to building classifiers in your own java code http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code.

Comment: You are quite right.  I ended up opting for De-serializing the trained models produced from Weka (if you save the trained classifier as a *.model) leveraging the Weka Java libraries.  It is interesting they don't let you naturally use the code tho, but for now the de-serialization solved my immediate problem.  I may look into implementing the Soureable interface for those methods as an exercise down the road, however.  Thank you for your help and the links!

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem for myself by turning the output of WEKA's -printTrees option of the RandomForest classifier into Java source code.

http://pielot.org/2015/06/exporting-randomforest-models-to-java-source-code/

Since I am using classifiers with Android, all of the existing options had disadvantages:

- shipping Android apps with serialized models didn't reliably work across devices
- computing the model on the phone took too much resources

The final code will consist of three classes only: the class with the generated model + two classes to make the classification work.